# Format string to make MySQL query using .format in Python way

Tags: python, mysql, string, formatting

So i have following rename statement that I want to execute:

```
"RENAME TABLE `my_table` TO `my_table_temp`, `my_new_table` TO `my_table`,
  `my_table_temp` TO `my_new_table`"
```

I want to make a function using this query so I could apply it to different tables.
The case is that I'm looking for best readable way of formatting string.
Tool of choice seems to be `.format` method and obviously I do not want to make something like this

```
"RENAME TABLE '{0}' TO '{1}', '{2}' TO '{3}',
  '{4}' TO '{5}'".format('my_table','my_table_temp','my_new_table','my_table','my_table_temp','my_new_table')
```

But what I do want to make is something like this

```
.format('my_table','my_table_temp','my_new_table')
```

and somehow just indicate numbers which should be replaced with each string.
Just to be clear - I do not want use 6 arguments for string formatting but just 3 and make each of them be repeated twice in string
 So I'm seeking an advice of how this should be implemented. Apologize if this question is silly and obvious but I just want to improve my code style to maximum level even in such details before it become too late and I find myself somewhere in gutter, writing awful crap using Python language

Comment: This isn't really a question about MySQL at all, but about standard Python string substitution. This isn't even a parameterized query.

Comment: There are six format `{}` braces while you are giving seven input.

Comment: Using the normal string formatting on an SQL query is dangerous. It can make your application vulnerable to SQL injections: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection . Sometimes you need to use it, but make sure you have no user generated content in the variables you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [42]: '{0}, {0}' .format('a')
Out[42]: 'a, a'

In [43]: '{0}, {0}' .format('a', 'b')
Out[43]: 'a, a'

In [44]: '{0}, {1}' .format('a', 'b')
Out[44]: 'a, b'
```

foramt string works like this.

so you only need to do:-

```
"RENAME TABLE '{0}' TO '{1}', '{2}' TO '{0}',\  
'{1}' TO '{2}'".format('my_table','my_table_temp',\
                         'my_new_table','my_table')

>>> 
RENAME TABLE 'my_table' TO 'my_table_temp', 'my_new_table' TO 'my_table',  'my_table_temp' TO 'my_new_table'
```

Comment: @micgeronimo sry i forgot ot edit my solution.I update my answer check it.